# CaptureScreen() works, verified, but event PrintPage doesn't, am I missing something?

Tags: printing

here is my code for printing. click print and dialog appears. if you click ok capture screenis initiated. Bitmap memoryImage becomes a bitmap of the current form is displaying. ive verified that it is correct and the image is captured succesfuly.

finally printDocument.Print() takes place. only prints one blank page. Ive tried changing it to e.Graphics.Color(Gray); and still no luck only prints a blank page.

obviously communication with printer is fine. My guess is that the page actually prints before the image is attatched, but ive never coded for printing before so im not sure how to rearange my code.

using System.Drawing.Printing;

//show print dialog (works great)

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            CaptureScreen();
            printDocument1.Print();
            //this.Close();
        }
    }

    Bitmap memoryImage;
```

//capture screen (works as well)

```
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(
            this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }
```

//drawimage from captured screen (doesn't work)

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,
           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: This code works fine on my printer.